# When importing an xml file, how to use parentId to map the hierarchy of key values in the xml file

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

```
    ValidationUtils.validate(input,
            ValidatorField.of("data", Rule.required()))
    ;
    ValidationUtils.validateArray(input.get("data"),
            ValidatorField.of("projectId", Rule.required(), Rule.number(Rule.NumberType.Long)),
            ValidatorField.of("parentId", Rule.number(Rule.NumberType.Long)),
            ValidatorField.of("milestoneId"),
            ValidatorField.of("title", Rule.required()),
            ValidatorField.of("content"),
            ValidatorField.of("timeStart", Rule.required(), Rule.number(Rule.NumberType.Long)),
            ValidatorField.of("timeEnd", Rule.required(), Rule.number(Rule.NumberType.Long)),
            ValidatorField.of("duration", Rule.required()),
            ValidatorField.of("progress", Rule.number(Rule.NumberType.Long)),
            ValidatorField.of("organizationIds"),
            ValidatorField.of("projectRelation")
    );
    var allData = new HashMap<>();
    input.get("data").forEach(param ->{
        allData.put(param.get("key").asText(),param);
    });
    allData.forEach((key, value) -> {
        System.out.println(key);
        System.out.println(value);
    });
```

I tried using the HashMap in the image above to form a key-value pair. The result was a key for a value, but my database field only had a parentId

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please paste the code itself in the question as text instead of using an image. Cheers!

Comment: Please read how to ask in Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Your question lacks a minimal reproducible example and you should explain better the problem, what you are trying to do and how your code work, including any libraries used.